# Google analytics application not sending data to the server

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to track one of my mobile app using google analytics. I have some how went through the tutorials and  added it to one of my basic applications. The code seems to be bug free, but still i am not getting any updates in my analytics dashboard. I am posting my main activity, analytics activity and manifest files for your consideration. For now, this is a basic app with 1 screen, similar to 'hello world'. Since I am new to android, hope your help will be useful.

Main Activity

```
        package com.example.dell.testanalytics;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    import android.app.Application;

    import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
    import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Logger;
    import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
    import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
        private Tracker mTracker;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            // [START shared_tracker]
            // Obtain the shared Tracker instance.
            AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
            mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
            // [END shared_tracker]


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


// [START screen_view_hit]
        String name = getString(R.string.test);
        Log.i(TAG, "Setting screen name: " + name);
        mTracker.setScreenName("Image~" + name);
        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
        // [END screen_view_hit]
        return false;
    }
}
```

AnalyticsApplication Java file

```
package com.example.dell.testanalytics;
import android.app.Application;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Logger;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;


public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application {
    private Tracker mTracker;

    synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
        if (mTracker == null) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
            mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
        }
        return mTracker;
    }
}
```

Manifest File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dell.testanalytics" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".AnalyticsApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: HI @faz, Have you also added "ga_trackingId" in an xml fiel for your app?

Comment: notin a xml file. I have added the json configuration file I generated from google. I thought the tracking id would be taken from that

Comment: But the global tracker file is generated in the app/build folder. That has the tracking id as well.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using only fires the tracker when a menu option is selected. If you want the tracker to fire when the screen is simply loaded then put it in the onResume override:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // [START screen_view_hit]
    String name = getString(R.string.test);
    Log.i(TAG, "Setting screen name: " + name);
    mTracker.setScreenName("Image~" + name);
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
    // [END screen_view_hit]
}
```